Fix distribution $u$, find a distribution $\tilde u$ satisfying $x\cdot\tilde u=u$

Prove that, for every distribution $u\in\mathcal D'(\mathbb R)$,there exists a distribution $\tilde u\in \mathcal D'(\mathbb R)$ satisfying $x\cdot\tilde u=u$.

It seems that it can be solved by Fourier Transform. But this is an exercise in the chapter which is before Fourier Transform. So can I solve this without fourier transform?
Maybe I can consider the support set of $u$, but I still cannot solve that.

Do you use the notation $\langle u, \varphi \rangle$ for the action of the distribution $u$ on the test function $\varphi$?

@md2perpe, yes, and thank you for your answer!

Let $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ be a test function.
Note that if $\varphi(0)=0$ then there exists $\psi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ such that $\varphi=x\psi$. In that case we can set $\langle \tilde u, \varphi \rangle = \langle u, \psi \rangle$.
Otherwise take $\rho\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ such that $\rho(0)=1$ and set $\hat\varphi=\varphi - \varphi(0)\rho$. Then $\hat\varphi(0)=0$ so we can define $\langle \tilde u, \hat\varphi\rangle$ by above. Set $\langle\tilde u, \rho\rangle=C$. Then we have
$$
\langle \tilde u, \varphi \rangle
= \langle \tilde u, \hat\varphi + \varphi(0)\rho \rangle
= \langle \tilde u, \hat\varphi \rangle + \varphi(0) \langle \tilde u, \rho\rangle
= \langle \tilde u, \hat\varphi \rangle + \langle C\delta, \varphi\rangle.
$$
Thus we can define $\tilde u$ by applying $u$ to $\varphi-\varphi(0)\rho$. Different choices of $\rho$ will only make the result differ by a multiple of $\delta$ which itself satisfies $x\delta=0.$

Maybe there is a typo? I think $u$ should do action on $\frac{\varphi-\varphi(0)\rho}x$ instead of $\varphi-\varphi(0)\rho$.

According to my understanding, we have $\langle \tilde u-C\delta,\varphi\rangle=\langle u,\frac{\varphi-\varphi(0)\rho}x\rangle$. And can we get $\langle \tilde u,\varphi\rangle=\langle u,\frac{\varphi-\varphi(0)\rho}x\rangle$ because of $x\delta=0$? (I'm not sure about this step) If true, we can define $\tilde u$ by the last formula.

But if we have $\langle \tilde u,\varphi\rangle=\langle u,\frac{\varphi-\varphi(0)\rho}x\rangle$, then we must have $\varphi(0)\langle \tilde u,\rho\rangle=0$. Is there anything wrong?

@TaD. You're right; it should be that $u$ acts on $\frac{\varphi-\varphi(0)\rho}{x}.$

@TaD. We can define $\tilde u$ by taking such a $\rho$ and then setting $$\langle \tilde u, \varphi \rangle = \langle u, \frac{\varphi-\varphi(0)\rho}{x}\rangle.$$ The result will be dependent on the choice of $\rho$ but different results will only differ by a multiple of $\delta$.
